# When passing the values into ListView I am getting an erroe NullPointerException but still the data is showing in the list after the error pop up

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am taking an array from another activity and passing it to the adapter to set it as the adapter for ListView. When I run the app and click on the button to see the ListView a message popped up saying "Unfortunately The app is stopped" but after that the list is showed. I don't know how this is happening cause after the message the app should be closed but it showing the list.

And when I am seeing in the Logcat it is showing NullPointerException. Please help me as I don't know what to do next.

Here is the code :

```
 public class ForecastDisplay extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forecast_display);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String [] stringArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string-array");
    Log.v(TAG, "The temperature of "  + "is " + stringArray[2]);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ForecastDisplay.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.forecast_display, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
`

And here is the snapshot of the LogCat :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlU5i.png

Comment: post your logcat....

Comment: It is already posted, see the image link at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your "item" array is not instantiated in your "onOptionsItemSelected".  This would result in a NULL pointer whenever any item is highlighted or selected.

Make sure your array is instantiated, and in scope.